# How to reflect locales changes without restarting the node server - i18n?

Tags: node.js, server, internationalization, i18next

In my project, I want to update locales JSON file dynamically.
But when I update its not reload in browser directly. To reflect changes in browser I have to restart my server (Node).
I am using i18n for same.

Is it possible to update locales without restarting node server?

I also read about i18next. But did not get solution. Can anyone please explain solution.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using webpack as your bundler there is a webpack plugin [i18next-hmr](https://github.com/felixmosh/i18next-hmr) that adds a watcher on the locale folder and Hot reload translations in the browser & server.

The lib is able to work without a webpack on the server, it can "connect" to the client webpack and trigger change in the server as well.